# Upload tempfile in Django

Tags: python, django, upload, temporary-files

I have a form where a user submits a text file ('example.txt'). I want to parse some data from that text file ('example.txt') and convert it into another text file ('modified.txt') and store it elsewhere.

I've created a model with a FileField that has a upload_to='converted/

I've created a tempfile and I am trying to save it into that model. Upon saving the instance of that model, I am receiving this error message:

AttributeError: '_io.BufferedRandom' object has no attribute '_committed'

Here is what my code looks like:

```
my_data = parse_data(example_file)

temp_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
json_text = json.dumps(my_data)
json_byte = str.encode(json_text)

temp_file.write(json_byte)
temp_file.name = example_file.name

file_instance = MyFileModel(file=temp_file)
file_instance.save()
temp_file.close()
```

Comment: This is a bit weird. Why do you want to create a temp for explicitly? Django will hold your file in memory until you save it, so surely you should do the parsing at that point.

Comment: I'm trying to upload to amazon s3, and I'm not really sure how to directly upload a new file. Is there another alternative?

Comment: If you want to upload a new file to Amazon S3 directly, you should use [`S3.Client.upload_fileobj`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj), where `Fileobj` is probably just `request.FILES['uploaded_file']`, but you should open another question for that.